# String.Format Doesn't Format a String

Tags: .net, string.format

It seems as though String.Format won't format a string as an input. Am I doing something wrong, or is this just native behavior?

Input : 0.37

This doesn't work.

```
string x = String.Format("{0:P}", myString)
```

Output : 0.37

This does.

```
string x = String.Format("{0:P}", Convert.ToDecimal(myString))
```

Output : 37.00 %

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is expected behavior for 'composite formatting'.

Your first example is attempting to apply numerical formatting rules to a string.  Your second example is attempting to apply numerical formatting rules to a number that can have decimal positions.

See [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(VS.80).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The format option you are trying to apply only works for numbers.  There is no concept of smart strings in .NET in which the CLR inspects the string for a type.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I doing something wrong, or is this just native behavior?

That's native behaviour. It's basically not the job of `Format` to interpret string input. `Format` assumes that the user supplies the right data – in your case, *numeric* data. A string isn't numeric, even if it *represents* a number (this is the all-important distinction in CS between a value/semantics and its representation/syntax!).